# Autodesk Inventor Make Holes on Different Edges Based on One Line

Tags: modeling, cad, technical-drawing, autodesk-inventor

I need to invent a construction based on standard square tubes with holes placed in certain distance from each other and from ends of the tubes:

[image]

I also need to imagine the tube with holes as a parametric part. Therefore I want to base all the holes on alone sketch line with points, something like the following:

[image]

How can I base all the tube holes on the above sketch line?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean with "base all the holes"? What is missing in the second picture that you cannot use it like that?

Comment: @OpticalResonator I mean that every point on the line should produce 4 holes on the tube. I can make the second picture, but I cannot make the first picture using the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels a little unintuitive, because the part is a square tube, but you can use the function Circular pattern. Select the holes on one plane as elements to repeat, select 4 repetitions and as turning axis the axis along the tube, then the holes get placed in the desired fashion.

Comment: A also wanted to know how can one easily project such a line to all 4 faces, but the way you described is enough to make the holes I need, thank you

Comment: This sounds good. To make the answer more complete, it could mention how a sketch driven pattern makes sense for the first plane, to make it as robust as possible. Then circular pattern the sketch driven pattern to the other faces.